# new spark.sql.shuffle.partitions value not used after checkpointing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark's Structured Streaming application with checkpointing to write output in parquet and using the default spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 200. I need to change the shuffle partitions but the new value is not used. Here is the content of a checkpoint offset after the application is restarted:

```
{"batchWatermarkMs":1520054221000,"batchTimestampMs":1520054720003,"conf":{"spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"200"}}
```

Do I need to set the number of partitions in the code instead of setting it with --conf?

Answer (score 8):

The number is restored from checkpoint, it will only change if you delete the checkpointed data and restart it with a "clean slate".

This makes sense, because if you have checkpointed data, Spark needs to know from how many partition directories it needs to restore the previous state.

Comment: It looks like I didn't make it clear. The offset as shown above is a newly committed offset after the application is restarted with a new shuffle partition value which I verified from the Spark Web UI's environment tab but newly committed offsets are still using the previous value. It is not very flexible if checkpointed data needs to be deleted for this change to take effect.

Comment: @user1373186 Did you have checkpoint data when you restarted the app?

Comment: Yes, checkpoint data already existed prior to restarting the app. Both old and new committed offsets have the same number of shuffle partitions. I also verified this to be the case from Spark's web UI after restarting the app and saw the number of tasks corresponding to the previous number of shuffle partitions (200) even when the current default is set to 4 be using the --conf argument.

Comment: @user1373186 Then my answer holds. You cannot change the number of partitions while you have datacin your checkpoint.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov @user1373186 do you delete the entire checkpoint directory to incorporate the new `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` value?  also if the checkpoint is deleted then the data already processed will be re-processed from the source resulting in duplicates right?

Comment: @thePurplePython Yes to both of your questions :)

Comment: This is still true, as of 2022 and spark 3.3.0: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#additional-information

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restore your application from the point where you had stopped along with changing the shuffle partitions size then you have two options

Use starting offset option in spark configurations

1. Open the latest offset file make note of the offsets and Delete the checkpoint directory
   Ex - In this example there are 10 partitions from source topic

   "startingOffsets": "{"topicAName":{"9":2528,"7":2633,"0":2705,"3":2018,"5":2749,"6":2857,"2":2145,"8":1916,"1":2094,"4":1932}}"
2. Pass the above config in spark configurations

Modify checkpoint all files (Works only if you don't have any state in your application, not recommended unless you are very sure and there is no other way)

1. Modify the offset file to have the latest offset file only and modify the configs in it

   "spark.sql.shuffle.partitions":"200" to value which you choose