# Could not change 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' in stateful spark structured streaming application

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a stateful (with flagMapGroupsWithState) spark structured streaming application.

By the current design of spark, seems there is **no way** to change **'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions'** once the application has been started - unless I stop the application, delete the checkpointed data (per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49082500)), and restart from clean - which is *unacceptable* because this way I will lost all in-middle states stored in checkpoint.

How can I scale out my application under this limitation without losing data?

Say I started the application on 10 nodes with `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 10 nodes * 4 cores/node * 3 = 120`, and sometime later I need to scale out the cluster by adding another 20 nodes.

I simply could not figure out a solution to let spark utilize the new added nodes, if I could not change 'spark.sql.shuffle.partitions' to a bigger value. Spark will still partition datasets to 120 partitions, which means part of the nodes will be idle.